# how to compare two string result show old column change text and new change text

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

The function below tells me the words  that have been changed, but i want those Column name also words returned which have been changed as well. How can i modify this function to tell me the Strings Column Name which have been changed..

> Like=> 'company_name :green Market' Changed to 'company_name: green super Market'

i am new in SQL SERVER PLEASE HELP ME

```
     SELECT dbo.CharDiff('{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5877c25b7c32d41827306d63"),
        "salt" : "ezmMjMn4A2cEb7ZZcc2cXQ==",
        "company_name" : "green Market",
        "designation" : "manager",
        "email" : "abc@gmail.com",
        "fcm_token" : "eqTXWSrYd",
        "full_name" : "John",
        "mobile_number" : "123456789",
        "password" : "Q2uQlO",
        "user_type" : "Customer",
        "is_active" : true,
        "is_approved" : true,    
        "role" : "user"
    }','{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5877c25b7c32d41827306d63"),
        "salt" : "ezmMjMn4A2cEb7ZZcc2cXQ==",
        "company_name" : "green super Market",
        "designation" : "manager",
        "email" : "abc@gmail.com",
        "fcm_token" : "eqTXWSrYd",
        "full_name" : "John",
        "mobile_number" : "123456789",
        "password" : "Q2uQlO",
        "user_type" : "Customer",
        "is_active" : true,
        "is_approved" : true,    
        "role" : "user"
    }');

    Alter function dbo.CharDiff(@oldtext nvarchar(max), @newtext nvarchar(max))

 returns nvarchar(max) as begin
   declare @retval as nvarchar(max); set @retval = '';
   declare @c as integer; set @c = 0; -- counter
   declare @t as nvarchar(max);

   -- if the strings match then there is no difference
   if @oldtext <> @newtext
   begin
      -- find the first non-matching character
      while substring(@oldtext, @c, 1) = substring(@newtext, @c, 1) set @c = @c + 1;

      -- remove up to the first non-matching character for both strings
      set @newtext = RIGHT(@newtext, len(@newtext) - @c + 1);  
      set @oldtext = RIGHT(@oldtext, len(@oldtext) - @c + 1);

      -- if the strings are different length then reverse them so you can start at 1 
      set @oldtext=reverse(@oldtext);  
      set @newtext=reverse(@newtext);
      set @c = 0;  -- reset the counter

      while substring(@oldtext, @c, 1) = substring(@newtext, @c, 1) set @c = @c + 1;
      set @newtext = RIGHT(@newtext, len(@newtext) - @c +2);
      set @oldtext = RIGHT(@oldtext, len(@oldtext) - @c +2);

      set @oldtext=ltrim(rtrim(reverse(@oldtext)));
      set @newtext=ltrim(rtrim(reverse(@newtext)));

      set @retval = '[' + @oldtext + '] to [' + @newtext + ']';
   end;

   return @retval;
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You should turn it into a table valued function. See [here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191165.aspx) for an example.

Comment: how do this explain